Raspberry pi 5 running Blender..?
Raspberry pi 5 running Blender..?
hi this is SorenaSenpai, I have Raspberry Pi 5 I want to
Run Blender but it said I need OpenGl 3 or higher is it
possible? if yes how do I install it?
1 more question: I download a Project and it has build inside
how do I install it???
Thank you for your kind comment.

which project are you asking about?

you know what never mind that one, can help me with blender?

I'm no expert, but I open Blender on my Rasberry Pi 5 by using the following command in a terminal:
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=true blender

This opens Blender with a software renderer rather than a hardware one (which the Pi doesn't have.)  Simply type that into a terminal prompt.  It's not fast, but Blender works.
I wrote this line on a document, made it executable, set it to open with the Terminal, and put it on my desktop.  It's a workaround, but it does work. I'm sure there's a better way to do this but once I got it to work I stopped caring.
I suppose I should note that this is after installing Blender the normal way with apt or nala.
sudo nala install blender

